# Ubuntu 22.04.03 issue after system upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

Recently I upgraded the system using `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` commands. After the latest upgrade (kernel version 6.2.0.36) Wifi, Ethernet, Bluetooth, audio, and touchpad have stopped working. During the boot process, I logged in using the old kernel version (5.15.0.72) and everything works smoothly in this version. Now what should be the recommended approach? Should I upgrade the system again by logging in using the old kernel version? Will the upgrade erase the (5.15.0.72) version from the system or it will replace (6.2.0.36)?

Comment: No, you need not reinstall - it won't help. Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out. Also for my understanding, I wish to know if I upgrade the system by logging into 5.15.0.72 (currently no.2 in the boot menu ), will it upgrade kernel version 6.2.0.36 (currently default and latest one) in the system to some latest release let say 6.2.0.38 if there is the latest release available? Also, will there be still a copy of 5.15.0.72 left in the system?

Comment: IT is important to run the upgrades from the working kernel, because that way it won't get deleted..

Comment: Thank you. Will try to run the update in a couple of days and post the update here

Comment: The system is functioning normally with the latest kerne version as well without making any additional changes. Closing this question from my end as i don't have anything specific to update on this

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu typically keeps three kernels available on a system for just this reason.   If you update and boot into the new kernel and some devices don't work, you can then reboot again and use the grub menu to select a previous kernel.

If that previous kernel works, you then have several options:

- Ignore the new broken kernel and and keep booting the old one that works
- Try to reinstall the new kernel, with the assumption that something went wrong when the corresponding initrd with drivers was built and try to boot it again after the initrd is rebuilt.
- Wait for another new kernel to be released and see if it fixes the problem.
- If the vendor for your device supports linux, you may be able to download source for the driver from their website and see if that works better than what came with the kernel.  (This is the best option if the device never worked.)
- Note also that Ubuntu distributes "HWE" kernels (hardware enablement, from the *next* version of Ubuntu from the one you have installed) that may also include newer drivers.
- If you are super ambitious and reinstalling the distro's kernel package doesn't work, it might be possible to download a newer (pre-release) kernel source version and compile it, making sure you explicitly configure the needed drivers.  Note however, that some of these kernels may have untested bugs and some need matching tools that may not be included (yet) with your version of the OS.

Note that you should keep the system booted into the working kernel.  That way, `apt autoremove` will not remove the currently booted working kernel even if it appears outdated.